# Python не находит библиотеку при запуске от имени не root пользователя

Tags: python, ubuntu, root, wxpython, idle

Имеется система Ubuntu 18.04 с установленными IDLE, Python2.7 и 3.6 и библиотекой wxPython Phoenix. Суть проблемы заключается в том, что при запуске IDLE или IDLE(using Python3.6) из меню приложений Gnome от имени обычного пользователя, IDLE ***независимо от версии Python*** не находит WX и, следовательно, при попытке выполнения кода типа приведённого ниже он выдаёт нижеприведенную ошибку.

Код:

```
import platform
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(
            self, None, size=(500, 200), title='Version Info'
        )
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        py_version = 'Python version: ' + platform.python_version()
        wx_version = 'wxPython version: ' + wx.version()
        os_version = 'Operating System: ' + platform.platform()

        main_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        size = (20, -1)
        main_sizer.Add(
            wx.StaticText(panel, label=py_version), 0, wx.ALL, 5
        )

        main_sizer.Add(
            wx.StaticText(panel, label=wx_version), 0, wx.ALL, 5
        )

        main_sizer.Add(
            wx.StaticText(panel, label=os_version), 0, wx.ALL, 5
        )

        panel.SetSizer(main_sizer)

        self.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suhestvitelnoe/py/helloworld.py", line 2, in <module>
    import wx
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wx'
```

Но, если запустить данный сценарий через терминал(командой указанной ниже) от имени root или запустить IDLE от имени root, то всё функционирует правильно и код выполняется так как нужно, а если запустить сценарий и/или IDLE от имени обычного пользователя, то Python не находит WX.
Команда:

```
su
python3.6m /home/suhestvitelnoe/py/helloworld.py
```

Как костыль, было принято решение изменить текст ярлыка запуска IDLE и заставить, таким образом запускаться его от имени root, приведя файл /usr/share/applications/idle-python3.6.desktop к такому виду(смотрим ниже).
Вывод команды cat /usr/share/applications/idle-python3.6.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IDLE (using Python-3.6)
Comment=Integrated Development Environment for Python (using Python-3.6)
Exec=su -c "/usr/bin/idle-python3.6"
Icon=/usr/share/pixmaps/python3.6.xpm
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Development;
StartupNotify=true
```

Как решить данную задачу? Как сделать библиотеку WX доступной всем пользователям в системе?

Comment: А как вы устанавливали свою библиотеку? На сколько помню, у рута свои директории. По этому если вы установили библиотеку от рута, то только он ее и видит. Возможно вам просто стоит сделать pip install от обычного пользователя?

Comment: ОП, если у вас пыхтон3, то вы должны использовать wxPython 2.9-Phoenix, а вот версия 2.8 работает только со вторым пыхтоном. Сделайте ``apt-get remove python3`` и после этого ``apt-get install --reinstall python2.7 wx-common python-wxtools python-wxgtk3.0``